# Field always equipped with arbitrary degree extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $K$ be a field. Over finite field $F_p$ or rational $Q$, it is clear there are extensions of any degree. The former is obtained by taking the muliplicative group adjoining units in $\overline{F}_p$ and the latter is obtained by considering Eisenstein applied to any $Z[x]$ irreducible polynomial. The Eisenstein argument applies to function field case as well. Hence the statement holds for function fields.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Is it true that in general $K$ will always have arbitrary degree of extensions? If so, how do I see this? If not, what is the counter example?

Comment: Try $K=\mathbb C$ for a counterexample.  or, $\overline {\mathbb F_p}$ since you mentioned it.

Comment: @lulu OK. So for algebraically closed, it is not going to work. Suppose $K$ is a proper subfield of algebraically closed field. Does this still hold?

Comment: Try $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @lulu I see. Thanks.

Comment: I forget the details, but I believe [Artin-Schreier](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf) tells us that fields "like" $\mathbb  R$ are the only finite degree subfields of algebraically closed fields.  In particular, any such proper subfield must have degree $2$.

Comment: @lulu It seems this post answers the question. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/304516

Comment: More interesting example: consider $K=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty\Bbb F_{p^{2^k}}$. Then $K$ has extensions of every odd degree, but none of any even degree.